# Django + gunicorn + systemd problems

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, systemd

I'm trying to setup gunicorn with systemd for my django project but it fails to load another library of my project.

```
File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
gunicorn[6043]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
gunicorn[6043]: ImportError: No module named 'templates'
```

Templates is another part of the project that is in a separate directory. I would get the same error if I try to run the site without `/home/ubuntu/templates/` in my `$PYTHONPATH`, I've added the pythonpath in my systemd unit file but it didn't do anything.

I can successful run gunicorn with this command:

`/home/ubuntu/venv/bin/gunicorn --pid /tmp/pid-gunicorn site_gfa.wsgi:application -b 0.0.0.0:8083`

But I fails in systemd

Systemd Unit File

```
[Unit]
Description="Site"
After=network.target

[Service]
PIDFile=/tmp/pid-gunicorn
User=ubuntu
Group=users
Environment=PYTHONPATH='/home/ubuntu/templates/'
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/gfa-apps/
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/venv/bin/gunicorn --pid /tmp/pid-gunicorn site_gfa.wsgi:application -b 0.0.0.0:8083
PrivateTmp=true
Type=forking

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I'm running CentOS7 with Python 3.4 and gunicorn 19.4.5
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it, the Environment var in systemd unit file shouldn't have quotes around it.

```
[Unit]
Description="Site"
After=network.target

[Service]
PIDFile=/tmp/pid-gunicorn
User=ubuntu
Group=users
Environment=PYTHONPATH=/home/ubuntu/templates/
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/gfa-apps/
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/venv/bin/gunicorn --pid /tmp/pid-gunicorn site_gfa.wsgi:application -b 0.0.0.0:8083
PrivateTmp=true
Type=forking

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```